# "fatal:division by zero attempted" while trying to replace a part of string

Tags: awk

I have a line like this:

```
first: val1       second: 6/Hi/how//I///, 5/Hi/how//you///, 8/Hi/how//she///     third: special
```

I want only the second field. In the second field I need everything after `second:`. Using this code, I'm able to reach my goal:

```
awk -F '\t' '/second:/ { split($2, a, / /); print a[2] }'
```

Now I have this:

```
 6/Hi/how//I///, 5/Hi/how//you///, 8/Hi/how//she///
```

Now I want to replace `/Hi/how//` with `/`, so my expected output is like this:

```
first: val1       second: 6/I///, 5/you///, 8/she///     third: special
```

I changed my code to this:

```
awk -F '\t' '/second:/ { split($2, a, / /); gsub(//Hi/how///,"/",a[2]; print a[2] }'
```

but I encounter this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal division by zero attempted
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal division by zero attempted
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal division by zero attempted
```

What's wrong?

Comment: If your pattern contains slashes, enclose it in double-quotes. Like `"/Hi/how//"`, not `//Hi/how///`

Comment: @anubhava It was a typing mistake. I edited the post.

Comment: @oguzismail so my command should be like this: `awk -F '\t' '/second:/ { split($2, a, / /); gsub("/Hi/how//","/",a[2]; print a[2] }'`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $2 ~ /^second:/{ gsub(/\/Hi\/how\/\//, "/", $2) } 1' file
```

```
first: val1    second: 6/I///, 5/you///, 8/she///    third: special
```

There is no need to use `split` here. Note how `/` need to be escaped in your regex since `/` is a regex delimiter in `gsub` function.

Following `gsub` will also work with a quoted string instead of regex:

```
gsub("/Hi/how//", "/", $2)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I edit the gsub part in my code as you said, is it also a correct command to use?

Comment: Is it correct to use several gsub that are separated by `;` in one awk command? I want to replace `, ` with `-` too. Is it correct to use: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $2 ~ /^second:/{ gsub(/\/Hi\/how\/\//, "/", $2); gsub(/, /,"-", $2 } 1' file` ?

Comment: I only want to edit  `6/Hi/how//I///, 5/Hi/how//you///, 8/Hi/how//she///`? Isn't is a[2]?

Comment: `second: 6/Hi/how//I///, 5/Hi/how//you///, 8/Hi/how//she///` is `$2` so there is no real reason calling `split`. Just call `gsub` for `$2`

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I don't want to write output to a file, This command is used in a function and the result of this command will be returned by the function. so should I remove file at the end of command?

Comment: So it shouldn't be removed?

Comment: Sorry I stepped away from computer but my command is fine and you need not remove anything